# Filter Method for Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, find

In my code, I've declared a variable "Warranty Code" as a variant, and then populated that variant as an array with 41 potential 2 character string values.

Now I'm looping through a range, and checking each cell in that range (the "MWWar" variable), to see if it matches one of the 41 strings in my array.

If it does, I want my code to do nothing, but if it doesn't, I want it to add one to my counter (the "BadWar" variable).

If the "WarrantyCodeFilter" variable does match, the code works fine and does nothing but go onto the next line. However, if it doesn't find a match in my array, it becomes "subscript out of range" error 9, and won't let me proceed.

I've tried the "If(Iserror) = true" to add to my counter, but it still wouldn't let me do it

How can I get the no match scenario to just add to my counter, and move on to the next line instead of erroring out?

```
For i = 2 To lr
    Set MWWar = Cells(i, MWWarCol)
    WarrantyCodeFilter = Filter(WarrantyCode, MWWar, True, vbTextCompare)
    If IsError(WarrantyCodeFilter(0)) = True Then BadWar = BadWar + 1
Next i
```

Comment: `WarrantyCodeFilter` won't throw an error. Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function): "The array returned by the Filter function contains only enough elements to contain the number of matched items."

Comment: Note that `Filter` also matches on *substrings*, so you'll need a different approach if you want an exact match.

Comment: @TimWilliams what approach would you use?

Comment: If your terms exist in a Range on a worksheet I'd use `Match()` against the range (you could use Match against the array, but it would be slower than against the range).  If you only have them as an array then a simple loop to check each element would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function [IsArrayEmpty](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) from Chip Pearson's website in order toc check if the filter gave a result

```
If Not IsArrayEmpty(WarrantyCodeFilter) Then
    'If IsError(WarrantyCodeFilter(0)) = True Then BadWar = BadWar + 1
    BadWar = BadWar + 1
End If
```

> ```
> Public Function IsArrayEmpty(Arr As Variant) As Boolean    
>     ' IsArrayEmpty
>     ' This function tests whether the array is empty (unallocated). Returns TRUE or FALSE.
>     '
>     ' The VBA IsArray function indicates whether a variable is an array, but it does not
>     ' distinguish between allocated and unallocated arrays. It will return TRUE for both
>     ' allocated and unallocated arrays. This function tests whether the array has actually
>     ' been allocated.
>     '
>     ' This function is really the reverse of IsArrayAllocated.
>     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>     
>     Dim LB As Long
>     Dim UB As Long
>     
>     Err.Clear
>     On Error Resume Next
>     If IsArray(Arr) = False Then
>         ' we weren't passed an array, return True
>         IsArrayEmpty = True
>     End If
>     
>     ' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array is
>     ' unallocated, an error will occur.
>     UB = UBound(Arr, 1)
>     If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
>         IsArrayEmpty = True
>     Else
>         ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>         ' On rare occassion, under circumstances I
>         ' cannot reliably replictate, Err.Number
>         ' will be 0 for an unallocated, empty array.
>         ' On these occassions, LBound is 0 and
>         ' UBoung is -1.
>         ' To accomodate the weird behavior, test to
>         ' see if LB > UB. If so, the array is not
>         ' allocated.
>         ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>         Err.Clear
>         LB = LBound(Arr)
>         If LB > UB Then
>             IsArrayEmpty = True
>         Else
>             IsArrayEmpty = False
>         End If
>     End If
>     
>     End Function
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It did the opposite and added one if it was an array, but I was able to flip it to work properly

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but if you fixed your problem it might be useful you add it here as a solution.

Comment: My variable BadWar was supposed to plus 1 every time it wasn't an array, but with the code as you had it, it added one each time it was an array. Just rewrote the line you gave me to:
'If IsArrayEmpty(WarrantyCodeFilter) = True Then
    BadWar = BadWar + 1'

Answer (score 0):

So, after some more digging, I found a significantly easier way to achieve my goal.

Instead of using the custom function as suggested above, and adding line:

```
If Not IsArrayEmpty(WarrantyCodeFilter)
```

I was able to incorporate the Match function as suggested by @TimWilliams in this manner

```
WarrantyCodeFilter = Not IsError(Application.Match(MWWar, WarrantyCode, 0))
```

Declared WarrantyCodeFilter as Boolean. Matched my cell (MWWar) against the array (WarrantyCode). This line returns true or false if the item is or isn't in my array. From there, I can do what I need with my counter.